# Right-align items in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div container (black outline) which contains 4 divs of equal length and height.

I want the 4 colored divs to be aligned right with equal spaces between them (assuming that each colored div is about 49.5% the height of container and width of each div is about 25% of container).

[image]

I tried to do this with flex but I'm not getting what I want.

Can someone please help me? Thank you so much in advance.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="purple"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>    
</div>

.container { }
.blue { }
.red { }
.purple { }
.green { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it seems that you have two columns inside a row, I suggest you use **three** flexboxes for this occasion.

Here is how this works:

```
.container (outer flexbox, flex-direction: row)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   .innerContainer   |   .innerContainer   |   .innerContainer   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------

.innerContainer (inner flexbox, flex-direction: column)
---------------   ---------------   --------------
|   (empty)   |   |    .blue    |   |    .red    |
---------------   |   .purple   |   |   .green   |
                  ---------------   --------------
```

Also, all `flex-box` children were set to `flex-grow: 1` so that they are all equal dimensions and they fill up the entire space.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 100px;
}
.innerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.blue, .red, .purple, .green, .innerContainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 2px 1px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer"></div>
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="purple"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you added margin: 2px 1px? Won't margin: 1px, create even more evenly spacing at the outer borders? Besides that it looks brilliant :)

Comment: @RMo I didn't see the sizing specifications in the question and I tried to make it look like the image. I was just trying to recreate the little spacing in between the colorful boxes.

Comment: It wasn't my question by the way :). But nvm that.

Comment: @RMo I just realized that and edited my comment. Oops =P

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me. This is exactly what I want, except for the space between the container and divs...however, I was able to fix that. Thank you very much @JonathanLam and Michael_B. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
    display: flex;                /* create flex container */
    flex-direction: column;       /* align children vertically */
    flex-wrap: wrap;              /* allow multiple columns */
    align-content: flex-end;      /* shift columns to container end */
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.container > div {
    margin: 5px;                   /* equal spacing between divs */
    width: calc(25% - 10px);       /* width less margin */
    height: calc(50% - 10px);      /* height less margin */
}

.blue   { background-color: blue; }
.purple { background-color: purple; }
.red    { background-color: red; }
.green  { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="purple"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/am6o2k8k/1/)