# how to keep a h title over a list if i use flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The question title is pretty much what i want to know.

How do I keep the title1,2,3 over the list and not in the left of it.

Do i need to add more classes?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>title1</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>listItem1</li>
    <li>listItem2</li>
    <li>listItem3</li>
  </ul>

  <h1>title2</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>listItem1</li>
    <li>listItem2</li>
    <li>listItem3</li>
  </ul>

  <h1>title3</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>listItem1</li>
    <li>listItem2</li>
    <li>listItem3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285631/aligning-divs-inside-a-flex-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *easy* solution is to add extra class called `column` (whith extra div tags) where you change the flex direction :

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h1>title1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>listItem1</li>
      <li>listItem2</li>
      <li>listItem3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1>title2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>listItem1</li>
      <li>listItem2</li>
      <li>listItem3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1>title3</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>listItem1</li>
      <li>listItem2</li>
      <li>listItem3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```